# Cognito User Pool Authorizer defined in openapi without hardcoded values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, openapi, aws-jwt-authorizer

I have a API Gateway Rest Api resource defined with this template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "Api gateway"
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      BodyS3Location: "./openapi-spec.yaml"
```

And the contents of `openapi-spec.yaml` [(based on this example)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html) being:

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.2"
info:
  title: SampleApi
paths:
  /test:
    get:
      summary: Test
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Ok
      security:
        - UserPool: [ ]
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        # ....

components:
  securitySchemes:
    UserPool:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: cognito_user_pools
        providerARNs:
          ### THIS VALUE ###
          - "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456789012:userpool/eu-west-1_abcd12345"
```

I'd like to be able to deploy this template in multiple environments/account and having this hardcoded providerARN is limiting that. So my questions are:

How can values for the `providerARNs` field be passed in dynamically?

If that can't be done, then are there any workarounds to this so that I don't have to hardcode the providerArns here?

*Note*: Already tried to use stage variables and they don't seem to work here.

Comment: How about generating the spec upon deployment and storing it under different keys in S3?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an existing Cognito user pool then you would have to define one using `AWS::Cognito::UserPool` in CloudFormation, then you can simply reference the arn of this user pool using `!GetAtt`.

But if you have an existing Cognito user pool then you can also import it to a stack using CloudFormation following these [steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html).

Here's an example:

`template.yaml`

```yaml
Resources:
  ApiGateway:
    Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
    Properties:
      BodyS3Location: "./openapi-spec.yaml"

  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      # ....
```

`openapi-spec.yaml`

```yaml
openapi: "3.0.2"
# ....
components:
  securitySchemes:
    UserPool:
      type: apiKey
      name: Authorization
      in: header
      x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: cognito_user_pools
      x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: cognito_user_pools
        providerARNs:
          - !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

Aswering this question even though it's late cause I struggled myself a lot to find an answer for this problem. I was able to do this by using the Stage Variables feature of api gateway. Your Authorizer declaration in open api spec file would look like this.

[image]

Your api gateway declaration will have to declare this stage variable like this in temaplate.yaml

[image]

I'm declaring this as parameter in template.yaml file :

[image]

Now don't get confused if you see this in your API Gateway->Authorizer:

[image]

This is exactly what it should look like. This will actually use the stage variable which is here in your stages->{stage_name}->stage variables:

[image]